# Javascript: How to safely open a user-provided URL in a new window

Tags: javascript, security, xss

On my intranet site I have a webpage with a text field and an icon next to that text field. Users should type a URL into this field but they *could* type anything at all.

When a user clicks the icon next to the text field, I want the URL in the text field to open in a new window *if this is safe to do* i.e. this should not expose any cross site scripting vulnerability.

- I do not care if the URL is valid. E.g. if the user has specified http://wwwfoo.garbage.wibble I would want a new window to open with that nonsense URL in the address bar and for the browser to display its standard error for a non-resolvable URL.
- I want to use only Javascript for this solution.
- I am aware that I should NOT attempt to do anything with the URL if it does not begin with http:// or https://. My question is whether there are any other security considerations.

Many thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should just validate it is a url when they save it.

Comment: To clarify, are you saving this url anywhere? Does it get displayed to other users? Or is it just a one off for that user alone to type in then open a new tab for themselves?